# Building search index for Json in cloudant

Tags: json, search, indexing, lucene, cloudant

I have built search index for sample db and run a search query in cloudant scussessfully. For example, I had a database as:

```
{
  "_id": "aardvark",
  "_rev": "3-fe45a3e06244adbe7ba145e74e57aba5",
  "min_weight": 40,
  "max_weight": 65,
  "min_length": 1,
  "max_length": 2.2,
  "latin_name": "Orycteropus afer",
  "wiki_page": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aardvark",
  "class": "mammal",
  "diet": "omnivore"
}
```

For indexing "_id" or "class" i can create search index as:

```
function(doc){
  index("default", doc._id);
...
}
```

or

```
function(doc){
  index("default", doc.class);
... 
}
```

However, I don't know how to index on Json format. For example, i have a Json format as:

```
  "_id": "08ff683d86484139",
  "_rev": "4-cf6f34c6a2a22780a646b86a3f8d1848",
  "lastUpdated": "2014-01-31 00:00:00",
  "issueId": 62655,
  "isThirdParty": true,
  "dateCreated": "2014-01-29 00:00:00",
  "attributeCollection": {
    "attributeArray": [
      {
        "updateable": false,
        "lookup": "issuetype",
        "issueAttributeDefinitionId": 13,
        "attributeType": 1,
        "name": "Web Type",
        "value": [
          "Improper Neutralization of Input During Web Page Generation"
        ]
      },
 "appReleaseId": 57,
  "hash": "953b33eca52938ab2d21e27eb171998b"
}
```

My question is how to index properties in "attributeCollection" of Json format. Particularly, how to index for

```
"name": "Web Type",
```

and

```
"value": ["Improper Neutralization of Input During Web Page Generation"]
```

Comment: Nguyen, I assume the use case you were trying to solve was related to filtering on name and/or value. I provided a solution to do that below, but it does not use "json" indexes. If the answer below does not solve your use case please let me know where it is lacking. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe you can create a json index on an array field of a sub-document, but you can create a search index for querying the `name` and `value` fields based on your document structure.

1. In the Cloudant dashboard select your database, tap the `+` next to Design Documents, and choose *New Search Index*.
2. Specify a name for the design document (ex. _design/attributes)
3. Specify a name for the index (ex. by_name_value)
4. Enter the following for the index function:

   ```
   function (doc) {
      if (doc.attributeCollection && doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray) {
         for (var i=0; i<doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray.length; i++) {
            if (doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].name) {
               index("name", doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].name, { store : true });
            }
            if (doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value) {
               for (var j=0; j<doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value.length; j++) {
                  index("value", doc.attributeCollection.attributeArray[i].value[j], { store : true });
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   ```

You can issue queries against this index as follows:

```
https://<yourcloudanthost>/<databasename>
/_design/attributes
/_search/by_name_value
?limit=10
&q=name:%27Web+Type%27+OR+value:%27Improper%20Neutralization%20of%20Input%20During%20Web%20Page%20Generation%27
&include_docs=true
```

Note: **attributes** is the name of the design document specified in step 2 and **by_name_value** is the name of the index specified in step 3.

The query decoded:

```
&q=
  name:'Web Type'
    OR 
  value:'Improper Neutralization of Input During Web Page Generation'
```

Here is a sample response for this query:

```
{
   "total_rows":1,
    "bookmark":"g2wAAAABaANkAChkYmNvcmVAZGIyLmJtLWRhbC1zdGFuZGFyZDIuY2xvdWRhbnQubmV0bAAAAAJiQAAAAGJf____amgCRj9_92eAAAAAYQBq",
    "rows":[
      {
         "id":"08ff683d86484139",
         "order":[
            0.0078043024986982346,
            0
         ],
         "fields":{
            "name":"Web Type",
            "value":"Improper Neutralization of Input During Web Page Generation"
         },
         "doc":{
            "_id":"08ff683d86484139",
            "_rev":"1-f4f6b73bbf3420412a5619e74f4cae00",
            "lastUpdated":"2014-01-31 00:00:00",
            "issueId":62655,
            "isThirdParty":true,
            "dateCreated":"2014-01-29 00:00:00",
            "attributeCollection":{
               "attributeArray":[
                  {
                     "updateable":false,
                     "lookup":"issuetype",
                     "issueAttributeDefinitionId":13,
                     "attributeType":1,
                     "name":"Web Type",
                     "value":[
                        "Improper Neutralization of Input During Web Page Generation"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "appReleaseId":57,
            "hash":"953b33eca52938ab2d21e27eb171998b"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

You can learn more about how to create and query search indexes here:

https://docs.cloudant.com/search.html#